# Extension of classical Liouville operator

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, computational-physics, hamiltonian, simulations, phase-space

Let us consider a classical Hamiltonian system described by the Hamiltonian 
\begin{equation}
H(q,p) =\frac{p^2}{2m}+V(q)
\end{equation}
where we stick to the case of single particle for simplicity. I am interesting in the dynamics generated by the extended Liouville operator
\begin{align}
i\mathcal L = \frac p m\frac{\partial}{\partial q}-V'(q)\frac{\partial}{\partial p}-V'''(q)\frac{\partial^3}{\partial p^3}
\end{align}
The equations of motion generated by $e^{i\mathcal L t}$ can no longer be written in a linear symplectic form, because by interpreting $\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d t}\leftrightarrow i\mathcal L$
\begin{align}\label{eom}
\dot q = \frac{p}{m} \hspace{10mm}\dot p = -\frac{\partial V}{\partial q}
\end{align}
we would identically neglect the cubic derivative in the momentum. Is there a way to extend the above dynamical scheme in compliance with the modified Liouville operator? I am ultimately interested in a numerical method aimed at integrating $(q(t),p(t))$.

Answer (score 2):

I am not experienced with cubic PDEs... only Infinite dimensional such. Your system looks like the first quantum correction in [Wigner flows](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/206680/is-there-an-equivalent-of-probability-current-for-the-wigner-distribution) in phase space, but I cannot get much help from that magnificent formulation, off the cuff...

I could only formulate your problem in 19th century language.

You are seeking the Green's function for 
$$
\left (\partial_t - \frac{p}{m} \partial_q + V(q)'\partial_p    +V(q)'''\partial_p^3  \right   ) f(q,p)=0 ,
$$

One could Fourier-transform to $f(q,p)=\int dy ~e^{iyp} F(q,y)$ ,
$$
\left (\partial_t +\frac{i}{m} \partial_y \partial_q + iV(q)' y   -iV(q)''' y^3  \right   ) F(q,y)=0 ,
$$ 
but it may not be clear this is friendlier to you purposes.

Comment: Indeed, I am looking for a first order nonlinear correction in the propagation of Wigner functions for a nonlinear quantum system. It seems like the problem is not straightforward, but I can look up whether the reformulation in terms of Green function offers some computational advantage.